# Android studio Interstitial Ad always displayed

Tags: android, admob, interstitial

I'm using admob with android studio.
I made a simple test use:
From my mainactivity.java i launch an interstitial ad before going through to the mainactivity2.java.

When the Interstitial ad is dismissed, i close the mainactivity.java with a finish();
Request.

When i press the back button on my phone the Interstitial ad is showing again.

Can someone explain me why ? I mean the first activity is supposed to be closed, so this mean the ad create his own activity ?

Thanks for help.